# referencing .net full framework package from .net core 2

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have referenced a NuGet package `package A` that targets .NET Framework 4.6 assembly from a .NET Core 2.0 project. Let's assume that `package A` references `package B` which is also a .NET 4.6 NuGet package. Under the dependencies node I see `package A` with a warning saying that it might not be compatible with it, but I do not see `package B` under the `package A` node.

My understanding is that .NET Core 2.0 has a shim that should allow it to reference .NET Framework 4.6 packages assuming that the .NET Framework 4.6 package does not reference features not supported by the shim.

Comment: The "shim" provides very limited functionality. If possible, forget about it and purely migrate to something compliant to .NET Standard.

Comment: What's the question here? Is is that you don't see package B listed?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't see package B listed. However, if I manually add a reference to package B it seems to build. Are you saying that I should not reference full framework packages from a .net core 2 project because the support is unreliable?

Comment: If you need Windows functionality, then you should target .NET Framework. If you are including a library which targets .NET Framework 4.6 and you are building with .NET Core 2.0, then you should take a look at .NET Standard (see [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430005/net-core-and-full-framework-projects-in-one-solution/47432381#47432381) and [answers on other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348531/reference-a-net-4-6-2-project-in-a-netcore-project-vs2017-15-4-4/47359253#47359253) which are very similar for information about the .NET Standard)